# send multipart form with ajax - send file and text

Tags: ajax, jquery

i need to send some data and an image file with ajax .
i know that must use multipart form and formdata but i don't know how - i googled it and i found some way for send file, but i need to send whole form. 
this is my html form

```
<form id="formData" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" id="uploader"  name="image" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp, image/raw"/>
                <input type="hidden"  name="action" id="action" value="receiver"/>
                <input type="hidden"  name="route" id="route" value="image"/>
 </form>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope something like this might do it for you mate... :)

html

```
//Include this script in head

 <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

The `jQuery Form Plugin` allows you to easily and unobtrusively upgrade HTML forms to use AJAX. The main methods, `ajaxForm and ajaxSubmit`, gather information from the form element to determine how to manage the submit process. Both of these methods support numerous options which allows you to have full control over how the data is submitted

```
 <div id='preview'></div>
 <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
    <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
 </form>
```

Script File

```
$('#photoimg').on('change', function() 
 {
      $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview', //Shows the response image in the div named preview 
         success:function(){

         }, 
         error:function(){

          } 
       }).submit();
});
```

ajaximage.php

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];


$path = "uploads/";
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$name) //Stores the image in the uploads folder
}
```

You could get the values of fields like `action,route` etc using `$_POST` inside the `php` file.For mare details check the below link mate.. :)

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm